# Parse regular expression

Tags: c++, c++11, regex, state-machine

### Task:

This function searches given null terminated string `pStr` by given subset of
regular expression `pMatch`.

Return value is matched string appeared in `pStr`.

If nothing has matched, return value is empty string.

The subset of regular expression grammar is defined as follows:

- A string is set of 8-bit characters. Beware that it is not 7-bit.
- The metacharacter `\` is an escape character, that means any single letter
  appeared next used as is.
- The characters in squared brackets metacharacters `[` and `]` is a sequence
  of literal characters or metacharacters.
  Immediately after `]`, another metacharacters in curly braces `{` num `}` must
  be followed. The num is a sequence of digits which specifies the number of
  times the previous literal character or metacharacter sequence in squared
  brackets must be repeated.
  e.g. "`abc[def]{2}ghi`" matches "`abcdefdefghi`".
- The squared brackets metacharacters can be nested.
  e.g. "`abc[def[ghi]{3}jkl]{2}mno`" matches
  "`abcdefghighighijkldefghighighijklmno`".
- In case of matching pattern given by `pMatch` is a grammatical error, this
  function returns a string "`ERROR`".

### My Solution:

Define a state machine and put regular expression strings into stacks. When used then pop up, multiple by `N` times and push to stack again.

```
   escape <--       escape <----                        escape <-----
       |    |          |       |                           |        |
       |    |          |       |                           |        |
     normal --> repeatStrStart --> repeatStrEnd --> repeatNumStart --
       ^            ^          |                          |
       |            |          |                          |
       |            ------------                          |
       ----------------------------------------------------
```

### Code:

```
string PatternSearch(const unsigned char* pStr, const unsigned char* pMatch)
{
    enum status {
        normal,
        escape,
        repeatStrStart,
        repeatStrEnd,
        repeatNumStart
    };
    status current = normal;
    status restore = normal;
    const static string strErr = "ERROR";
    stringstream bufNormal;
    stringstream bufRepeat;
    stringstream bufTmp;
    stack<unsigned char> stackBracket;
    stack<string> stackRepeat;
    unsigned long repeat = 0;
    size_t check = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0; pMatch[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(current == normal) {
            if(pMatch[i] == '\\') {
                restore = current;
                current = escape;
            }
            else if(pMatch[i] == '[') {
                current = repeatStrStart;
                stackBracket.push(pMatch[i]);
            }
            else {
                bufNormal << pMatch[i];
            }
         }
         else if(current == escape) {
             if(restore == normal) {
                 bufNormal << pMatch[i];
                 current = restore;
             }
             else if(restore == repeatStrStart) {
                 bufRepeat << pMatch[i];
                 current = restore;
             }
             else if(restore == repeatNumStart) {
                 bufRepeat << pMatch[i];
                 current = restore;
             }
             else {
                 bufNormal.str(strErr);
                 bufNormal.clear();
                 break;
             }
         }
         else if(current == repeatStrStart) {
             if(pMatch[i] == '\\') {
                 restore = current;
                 current = escape;
             }
             else if(pMatch[i] == '[') {
                 stackBracket.push(pMatch[i]);
                 stackRepeat.push(bufRepeat.str());
                 bufRepeat.str("");
                 bufRepeat.clear();
             }
             else if(pMatch[i] == ']') {
                 if(stackBracket.empty() == false && stackBracket.top() == '[') {
                     current = repeatStrEnd;
                     if(stackBracket.size() > stackRepeat.size()) {
                         stackRepeat.push(bufRepeat.str());
                     }
                     else {
                         bufTmp.str("");
                         bufTmp.clear();
                         bufTmp << stackRepeat.top();
                         bufTmp << bufRepeat.str();
                         stackRepeat.pop();
                         stackRepeat.push(bufTmp.str());
                         bufTmp.str("");
                         bufTmp.clear();
                     }
                     stackBracket.pop();
                     bufRepeat.str("");
                     bufRepeat.clear();
                 }
                 else {
                     bufNormal.str(strErr);
                     bufNormal.clear();
                     break;
                 }
             }
             else {
                 bufRepeat << pMatch[i];
             }
         }
         else if(current == repeatStrEnd) {
             if(pMatch[i] == '{') {
                 stackBracket.push(pMatch[i]);
                 current = repeatNumStart;
             }
             else {
                 bufNormal.str(strErr);
                 bufNormal.clear();
                 break;
             }
         }
         else {
             if(pMatch[i] == '\\') {
                 restore = current;
                 current = escape;
             }
             else if(pMatch[i] == '}') {
                 if(stackBracket.empty() == false && stackBracket.top() == '{') {
                     stackBracket.pop();
                     try {
                         repeat = stoul(/*str=*/bufRepeat.str(), /*idx=*/&check);
                         if(check == bufRepeat.str().length()) {
                             bufRepeat.str("");
                             bufRepeat.clear();
                             while(repeat--) {
                                 bufRepeat << stackRepeat.top();
                             }


                             stackRepeat.pop();
                             if(stackRepeat.empty()) {
                                 bufNormal << bufRepeat.str();
                             }
                             else {
                                 bufTmp.str("");
                                 bufTmp.clear();

                                 bufTmp << stackRepeat.top();
                                 bufTmp << bufRepeat.str();

                                 stackRepeat.pop();
                                 stackRepeat.push(bufTmp.str());
                             }

                             bufTmp.str("");
                             bufTmp.clear();
                             bufRepeat.str("");
                             bufRepeat.clear();
                         }
                         else {
                             bufNormal.str(strErr);
                             bufNormal.clear();
                             break;
                         }
                     }
                     catch(invalid_argument e) {
                         bufNormal.str(strErr);
                         bufNormal.clear();
                         break;
                     }
                     catch(out_of_range e) {
                         bufNormal.str(strErr);
                         bufNormal.clear();
                         break;
                     }

                     if(stackBracket.empty()) {
                         current = normal;
                     }
                     else {
                         current = repeatStrStart;
                     }
                 }
                 else {
                     bufRepeat.str(strErr);
                     bufRepeat.clear();
                     break;
                 }
             }
             else {
                 bufRepeat << pMatch[i];
             }
         }
     }

     if(stackBracket.empty() == false || stackRepeat.empty() == false) {
         bufNormal.str(strErr);
         bufNormal.clear();
     }
     else if(current != normal) {
         bufNormal.str(strErr);
         bufNormal.clear();
     }
     else {
         bufTmp.str("");
         bufTmp.clear();
         bufTmp << pStr;

         if(bufTmp.str().find(bufNormal.str()) == string::npos) {
             bufNormal.str("");
             bufNormal.clear();
         }
     }

     return bufNormal.str();
 }
```

Comment: You're reinventing-the-wheel on purpose, rather than using `std::regex`?

Comment: Why invent a non standard regular expression format. Use an existing one rather than a completely new one. Also wheel.

Comment: @LokiAstari   No one wants to do these things on purpose. These are interview questions.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from a purely style point of view, nine levels of indentation is a substantial red flag, when you should be able to keep it at three.

So much indentation makes this code hard to read in the first place, which is not the sort of practice you want to get into, especially if your code will be read and evaluated by others.